# Expo Error starting tunnel Failed to install @expo/ngrok@^2.4.3 globally

Tags: npm, expo

I'm trying to run expo with a tunnel connection and I keep getting the following error:

`Error starting tunnel Failed to install @expo/ngrok@^2.4.3 globally: npm exited with non-zero code: 243`

I've tried installing this version of ngrok globally and just within my project as well as removing it to allow expo to do the install automatically. It did run successfully once by starting the project with `expo start` instead of `npm start` but this seems to no longer work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

run `npm install @expo/ngrok@2.4.3`

Comment: I'm sure that I did this at one point with no luck but it works now. I maybe forgot to restart the expo server after running this.

Comment: new vesion `npm i @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0`

Answer (score 8):

The instructions are not intuitive, so here is a fix:

1. `npm install @expo/ngrok`
2. `brew install ngrok`
3. `ngrok http 3000`
4. `expo start --tunnel`

Wish Expo simplifies this; they shouldn't have a button that says "tunnel" if there is an entire setup that's not properly explained.

Answer (score 2):

For yarn
`yarn global add @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Install ngrok and run it in terminal using this command **ngrok http 3000**.
Then in other terminal run **expo start**.
It will work surely.